# How to use a custom domain with ASP.NET Core + Kestrel + Nginx

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core, dns, kestrel

I have deployed my app to my virtual linux machine and everything works fine.

I have redirect the domain to my ip and it works fine.
The problem is when it redirects my domain to my linux machine ip the url shows my ip instead of the domain.

Here's my Nginx file:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name mydomain.co www.mydomain.co *.mydomain.co;

#return 302 http://www.mydomain.co;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:54662;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Here's my Program.cs file:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls("http://*:54662")
            .Build();
}
```

Heres goDaddy set up:
[image: Domain to IP redirection]